# Minkowski difference of two convex sets is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

Hi my question is quite straightforward, if we have two disjoint compact convex sets A and B, is their minkowski difference A-B then convex again?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know, for instance, that the Minkowksi sum of two convex sets is convex? The proof here is fairly trivial given that lemma. (And that the map $f(x)=-x$ preserves convexity - or, as happens to be the case, any linear map)

Comment: Minkowski difference, as it turns out, is not all that different from Minkowksi sum.

Comment: Okay, yeah I knew that the sums were convex, but I was a little in doubt about the difference. I have a further question, is it then also true, that if two convex sets are disjoint, then they're also separated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each point in $A-B$ is of the form $a-b$, where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.

Letting $a-b$ and $a^{\prime}-b^{\prime}$ be two points in $A-B$,
we note that for any $\theta\in[0,1]$,
$$
\theta\left(a-b\right)+\left(1-\theta\right)\left(a^{\prime}-b^{\prime}\right)=\left[\theta a+\left(1-\theta\right)a^{\prime}\right]-\left[\theta b+\left(1-\theta\right)b^{\prime}\right].
$$
What does this imply?

Comment: Okay Cool, then I have a further question! If two convex sets are disjoint, that implies that they are separated right?

Comment: You should ask a new question, as this is unrelated to your current question. Also, please consider upvoting/accepting correct/helpful answers.

Comment: I did, but my reputation is so low, that it doesn't let me upvote :)