# Minkowski difference of two disjoint convex closed sets is a closed convex set?

Tags: convex-analysis

So I have seen this result mentioned a few times but never with a proper proof. I know that the Minkowski difference of two disjoint convex sets is convex and that the Minkowski difference of two closed sets is not necessarily closed (?) I've tried to sketch a proof but haven't gotten very far yet. All help is appreciated!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882306/minkowski-difference-of-two-convex-sets-is-convex

Comment: Indeed that question is about two convex sets having a convex Minkowski difference.